# Use @hideItBot in a message

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need to use @hideItBot in my python script but i don't know how to use it.

Here it's a part of the code

```
message= 'hello'
hiddenMessage = '@hideItBot  ' + message
await client.send_message('iurzaiz', hiddenMessage)
```

hope you can help me,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`client.inline_query`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.bots.BotMethods.inline_query):

```py
results = await client.inline_query('hideItBot', message)
hiddenMessage = message = await results[0].click('iurzaiz')
```